# Showing exactness of a short sequence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Let $p: E \rightarrow B$ be a fibration with fiber $F:= p^{-1}(b), b\in B$ fixed. If $B$ is path connected,

**I have the following question**: How can I show that for any space $X$, the sequence $$[X,F] \rightarrow [X,E] \rightarrow [X,B]$$ is exact.

**P.S:** $\quad i: F\rightarrow E$ is the inclusion map. $\,\,$Also $p_\star:[X,E] \rightarrow [X,B]$ and $i_\star: [X,F] \rightarrow [X,E]$ are induced by $i$ and $p$.

This is all I understood so far. I know that we have to show that $ker 
 \,\,p_\star = Im \,\,i_{\star}$. Also, I know that $p_\star[f] = [p\circ f]$ where $f: X\rightarrow E$. I pretty much know all the definitions here but I havent built that much intuition to get a proof. I have just been stuck on this for couple of days. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does $\ker p_\ast$ mean?  Does $[X,E]$ have a group structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the definitions. You have a sequence
$$[X,F]\xrightarrow{\ i_* \ }[X,E]\xrightarrow{\ p_* \ }[X,B]$$
which you would like to show is exact, i.e., 
$$\operatorname{im}(i_*)=\ker(p_*) = \{[\phi]\in[X,E]\ |\ p_*[\phi] = [c_b]\},$$ 
where $c_b:X\to B$ is the constant map sending everything to $b$. So, you need to show that $\operatorname{im}(i_*)\subseteq\ker(p_*)$ and $\ker(p_*)\subseteq \operatorname{im}(i_*)$.

For the first inclusion, let $[g]\in[X,E]$ be an element of $\operatorname{im}(i_*)$. Then, $[g] = i_*[f] = [i\circ f]$ for some $[f]\in[X,F]$. Then, since $(p\circ i)(x)=b$ for all $x\in F$, we have:
$$p_*[g] = p_*[i\circ f] = [p\circ i\circ f] = [c_b].$$ 
This was the easy inclusion.

For the other inclusion, take a map $[g]\in\ker(p_*)$. Then, $p_*[g]=[c_b]$, or in other words, $p\circ g\simeq c_b$ as maps from $X\to B$. That is, there exists a homotopy
$$H:X\times I\to B,\quad H(x,0)=(p\circ g)(x),\quad H(x,1)=b.$$
This means that the square:
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    X @>{g}>> E\\ @V{i_0}VV @VV{p}V\\
    X\times I @>>{H}> B
    \end{CD}$$
commutes, where $i_0(x) = (x,0)$. I think I'll let you take it from here. Apply the lifting property of fibrations, and look at what the new homotopy does at $t=1$.

One minor comment here: path-connectedness of $B$ guarantees that all of the fibers $\{p^{-1}(b)\ |\ b\in B\}$ are homotopy equivalent, and so the choice of fibre doesn't matter. It also guarantees that there is up to homotopy, only one constant map $c_b:X\to B$.

Comment: By applying the lifting prpperty, we get a lift  say $\phi: X \times I \rightarrow  E$ such that $p \circ \phi =H$. Thus, $p \circ \phi(x,1) =H(x,1) =b$. This implies that $\phi (X \times \{1\}) \subseteq p^{-1}(b)= F$. Please, what do I do from here @C.Cain?

Comment: @Jaynot Great, now you're basically done. Remember that you also have $\phi(x,0)=g(x)$, so the map $\phi_1=\phi|_{X\times\{1\}}:X\to E$ is homotopic to $g$. That is, $[g]=[\phi_1]$. But as you noted, $\phi_1$ really maps into $F$, so if $\phi_1|_F:X\to F$ is the restriction of $\phi_1$ to it's image, then $$[g] = [\phi_1] = [i\circ\phi_1|_F] = i_*[\phi_1|_F].$$

Comment: Thank you so much @C.Cain. I was checking questions on fibrations on Mse and I came across this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195441/question-on-isomorphism-of-homotopy-groups. I was just wondering if you had time to look at this question. I am just trying to undestand every details of the so called "fibrations".

Comment: Ofcourse  I know that a map $p : (E,e) \rightarrow (B,b)$ yields the exact long sequence of homotopy groups $$
...\to \pi_n(F,e)\to \pi_n(E,e)\to \pi_n(B,b)\to \pi_{n-1}(F,e)\to...
$$ and that $p$ also induces an isomorphism $p_\star: \pi_n(E, F,e) \rightarrow \pi_n(B,b,b)$ for $n \ge 2$.If you have time, any help you provide on this will be appreciated. I am just a bit inquisitive in the question.

Comment: @Jaynot Happy to help. Unfortunately I don't have time, but my advice would be to think about why the inclusion $(F,e)\hookrightarrow(E,e)$ being null-homotopic implies that the long exact sequence reduces to short exact sequences
$$0\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\pi_n(E,e)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\pi_n(B,b)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\pi_{n-1}(F,e)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }0$$
and then apply Balarka Sen's section to the Splitting Lemma on page 147 of Hatcher.

Comment: Hi @C. Cain. Do you have some time to discuss a question on covering spaces?

Comment: @Jaynot If you have a question, you should ask it on the site. I'll keep an eye out for it and I'll answer it if I can.